# Get PID from process name with Node.js

Tags: node.js, process, cross-platform

How can I get the PID from a process name?

Specifically, there is a particular application that I need to control with my application. I know the executable name of the application. Before I start it up, I need to ensure that there are no other instances of it running, so I need the PID so I can kill any that are still running.

I need a cross-platform approach.

Comment: `ps -ef|grep <process-name> | awk {'print $2'}`

Comment: @aarosil Thanks. That's a -nix based solution. Is there a way to run that through Node.js that'll cause it to be able to work on Windows?

Comment: You could look at [process.platform](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_platform) and run a different command depending on the output, although 'nix cmds should work on win32 if you have cygwin or similar installed.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38033127/node-js-how-to-check-a-process-is-running-by-the-process-name