# node.js how to check a process is running by the process name?

Tags: node.js

i run node.js in linux, from node.js how to check if a process is running from the process name ?
Worst case i use child_process, but wonder if better ways ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use the ps-node package.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ps-node

```
var ps = require('ps-node');

// A simple pid lookup 
ps.lookup({
    command: 'node',
    psargs: 'ux'
    }, function(err, resultList ) {
    if (err) {
        throw new Error( err );
    }

    resultList.forEach(function( process ){
        if( process ){
            console.log( 'PID: %s, COMMAND: %s, ARGUMENTS: %s', process.pid, process.command, process.arguments );
        }
    });
});
```

I believe you'll be looking at this example. Check out the site, they have plenty of other usages. Give it a try.

Just incase you are not bound to nodejs, from linux command line you can also do `ps -ef | grep "YOUR_PROCESS_NAME_e.g._nodejs"` to check for a running process.

Comment: How this will work on windws. I think it will give error on windows

Comment: @Shyam as advertised on the `ps-node` home. It 'should' work on windows. If it doesn't then maybe it is worth a github issue.

Comment: Note: this module requires other software to be installed. This may not work for systems or containers that do not have the right tools installed.

Comment: Currently, it doesn't work at all. At least on Linux. Version: 0.1.6 
https://github.com/neekey/ps/issues/84

Answer (score 21):

A little improvement of code answered by **d_scalzi**. Function with callback instead of promises, with only one variable query and with switch instead of if/else.

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec;

const isRunning = (query, cb) => {
    let platform = process.platform;
    let cmd = '';
    switch (platform) {
        case 'win32' : cmd = `tasklist`; break;
        case 'darwin' : cmd = `ps -ax | grep ${query}`; break;
        case 'linux' : cmd = `ps -A`; break;
        default: break;
    }
    exec(cmd, (err, stdout, stderr) => {
        cb(stdout.toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) > -1);
    });
}

isRunning('chrome.exe', (status) => {
    console.log(status); // true|false
})
```

Comment: This one works like a magic in all platforms. Thanks!

Comment: Downvoted. This function will always return true on mac since there will be process 'px -ax | grep {query}‘

Comment: In the linux  platform how can i check the `isRunning` function with the software name like `chrome.exe`?

Answer (score 18):

The following should work. A process list will be generated based on the operating system and that output will be parsed for the desired program. The function takes three arguments, each is just the expected process name on the corresponding operating system.

In my experience ps-node takes WAY too much memory and time to search for the process. This solution is better if you plan on frequently checking for processes.

```js
const exec = require('child_process').exec

function isRunning(win, mac, linux){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        const plat = process.platform
        const cmd = plat == 'win32' ? 'tasklist' : (plat == 'darwin' ? 'ps -ax | grep ' + mac : (plat == 'linux' ? 'ps -A' : ''))
        const proc = plat == 'win32' ? win : (plat == 'darwin' ? mac : (plat == 'linux' ? linux : ''))
        if(cmd === '' || proc === ''){
            resolve(false)
        }
        exec(cmd, function(err, stdout, stderr) {
            resolve(stdout.toLowerCase().indexOf(proc.toLowerCase()) > -1)
        })
    })
}

isRunning('myprocess.exe', 'myprocess', 'myprocess').then((v) => console.log(v))
```

Answer (score 12):

Here's another version of the other answers, with TypeScript and promises:

```
export async function isProcessRunning(processName: string): Promise<boolean> {
  const cmd = (() => {
    switch (process.platform) {
      case 'win32': return `tasklist`
      case 'darwin': return `ps -ax | grep ${processName}`
      case 'linux': return `ps -A`
      default: return false
    }
  })()

  if( ! cmd ) {
    return false;
  }

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    require('child_process').exec(cmd, (err: Error | null, stdout: string, stderr: string) => {
      if (err) reject(err)

      resolve(stdout.toLowerCase().indexOf(processName.toLowerCase()) > -1)
    })
  })
}
```

```
const running: boolean = await isProcessRunning('myProcess')
```

Comment: the macos version always returns true because the call to `ps -ax | grep ${processName}` includes the process name, so it will be included in the output of the command. I suggest removing the grep from that version.

Answer (score 4):

For the related subject, here are some of the best packages:

#### Search by pid, name patterns and different means packages:

- [find-process](https://www.npmjs.com/package/find-process) 
  (The one that I found interesting for my needs)
- [ps-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ps-node)
- [process-exists](https://github.com/sindresorhus/process-exists)

#### Check only by pid

- [is-running](https://www.npmjs.com/package/is-running)

#### Example with find-process

Search by name

```
const processesList = await findProcess(
    'name',
    /.*?\/kidoAgent\/Broker\/process.js.*/ // regex pattern
);

console.log({ processesList });

if (processesList.length === 0) {
     /**
      * No process
      * (create it)
      */
     // ......
}
```

It return a list of found processes as array!

When running, for the `console.log({ processesList });` it show:

```
{
  processesList: [
    {
      pid: 7415,
      ppid: 2451,
      uid: 1000,
      gid: 1000,
      name: 'node',
      bin: '/opt/node-v12.4.0-linux-x64/bin/node',
      cmd: '/opt/node-v12.4.0-linux-x64/bin/node ' +
        '/home/coderhero/Dev/.../build/.../kidoAgent/Broker/process.js'
    }
  ]
}
```

Check the module for all the options and ways!

Comment: is-running is the best module here, as it doesn't require external programs installed to work.

Comment: If u need to only check by pid

Answer (score 2):

Another improvement to @musatin solution is to use a self-invoking switch statement instead of reassigning `let`;

```
/**
 * 
 * @param {string} processName The executable name to check
 * @param {function} cb The callback function
 * @returns {boolean} True: Process running, else false
 */
  isProcessRunning(processName, cb){
      const cmd = (()=>{
          switch (process.platform) {
              case 'win32' : return `tasklist`;
              case 'darwin' : return `ps -ax | grep ${processName}`;
              case 'linux' : return `ps -A`;
              default: return false;
          }
      })();
      require('child_process').exec(cmd, (err, stdout, stderr) => {
          cb(stdout.toLowerCase().indexOf(processName.toLowerCase()) > -1);
      });
  }
```

`cmd` will be assigned the result of the switch statement and results in code that's easier to read (especially if more complex code is involved, self-invoking switch statements means you only create the variables you need and don't need to mentally keep track of what their values might be).

Answer (score 0):

Here's an improved version of the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51084163/1743580) by [musatin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10005732/musatin) so that the code also works on macOS and Linux. The change is updating the "check" commands to correctly detect running processes:

```js
/**
 * Find running process(es) by name
 * @param {string} query Name of the process to find (e.g., "Notepad.exe")
 * @param {function} cb Callback function
 * @returns {boolean} True if at least one such process is running, false otherwise
 */
const isProcessRunning = (query, cb) => {
  let platform = process.platform
  let cmd = ''
  switch (platform) {
    case 'win32':
      cmd = `tasklist`
      break
    case 'darwin':
      cmd = `pgrep -l ${query} | awk '{ print $2 }'`
      break
    case 'linux':
      cmd = `pgrep -l ${query} | awk '{ print $2 }'`
      break
    default:
      break
  }
  require('child_process').exec(cmd, (err, stdout) => {
    cb(stdout.toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) > -1)
  })
}
```