# How to write code for checking if process is indeed Parallel in Node/JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, npm, parallel-processing

There are few/many packages that assert they process their some methods parallelly, like async npm package. For many methods including concat they claim they process it parallelly.

**How can the code be written to check if their claim is indeed true?**

I have written code, but it only shows the results after all the process are completed, so there is no way I can't check how the actual process was carried out (parallel or sequential).
[image]

```
const async =  require('async');
const fs = require('fs');

let file1 = 'Abc1.pdf';
let file2 = 'Abc2.pdf';
let file3 = 'Abc3.pdf';

async.concat([file1,file2,file3], fs.stat, function(err, results) {
    results.forEach(element => {
        console.log('concat results: ', element.birthtime);
    });
});

---output---
concat results:  2020-12-21T02:40:35.713Z
concat results:  2020-12-21T02:40:35.668Z
concat results:  2020-12-21T02:40:35.847Z
------------
```

async documentation: https://caolan.github.io/async/v3/docs.html#concat

Comment: Just to be clear here, the `async` library does not by itself make anything run in parallel.  The operation itself has to already be asynchronous for anything to run in parallel.  What the `async` library does is track asynchronous things (one or more) so you can control them or know when they're done.  If you put a long running synchronous loop into a function and pass that to the `async` library, it will NOT run in parallel.  It will block the main nodejs thread and not run in parallel with anything else.

Comment: If you use the right parallel-capable functions in `async` and pass it functions that are asynchronous in nature, then it will run those asynchronous operation in parallel.  FYI, you don't need the async library to do that at all.  You can do that with promise-based functions like the interface at `fs.promises` and `Promise.all()` without using the `async` library.

Comment: Did you checked some sort of [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38033655/7574023)

Answer (score 0):

you can write a sleep function for 10 sec inside concat and print the result and see if it output all in 10 sec then its is proccessing `||` else not.

Also add start and end time at the starting and compelition of program which will help you to identify eaisly

Comment: I did similarly  to what you have suggested but the time should be more than 10 sec in that case and the closing time for each task should be almost same.