# How can I wait for a check to test if a process is running to finish?

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, electron

I am writing an Electron app. I have this very simple function which at the moment is just returning an empty array:

```
async GetStuff()
{
   var result:string[] = [];

   var bExists = false;

   var exec = require('child_process').exec;

   exec("tasklist", (err:any, stdout:any, stderr:any) => {
       err = err;
       stderr = stderr;
       bExists = stdout.toLowerCase().indexOf("unixsrv.exe") > -1;
   });

   return result
}
```

As it is, it correctly reports if a process named "unixsrv.exe" is running or not.

Thing is, the function as it is will first hit the "return result" line and later will hit the "bExists = " line.

How can modify the above so that I do not return until I have the answer as to whether or not the process exists?

More generically: How can I synchronously test whether a process is running or not?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: you could try using `execSync` instead of `exec`.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer that works for me here:

[node.js how to check a process is running by the process name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38033127/node-js-how-to-check-a-process-is-running-by-the-process-name)

It is the answer posted there by Christiaan Maks

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).